# Error: Dataset not in Edit or Insert mode

Tags: delphi, delphi-tokyo

Versión de Delphi: DELPHI 10.3.1.

Según varios tópicos del tema la manera en la que estoy editando los registros con FireDAC es la correcta pero me sigue apareciendo este error.

Código:

```
qyInforme.Edit;
qyInforme.FieldByName('REG_DATA').AsDateTime := now;
qyInforme.FieldByName('REG_STATUS').AsInteger := 3;
qyInforme.ApplyUpdates();
qyInforme.Post;
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Comment: El error lo genera la llamada al método `Post`, pues al llamar a `ApplyUpdates` estándo el registro en edición, ocurre un `Post` implícito. Para cuando llamas a `Post` el _DataSet_ ya no está en edición. Si quieres hacer el `Post` explícito, cambia el orden de la llamada, primero `Post` y luego `ApplyUpdates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo diría que según [la documentación de Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.ApplyUpdates), una vez realizas el `ApplyUpdates`, ya no es necesario que ejecutes el `Post`.

Es más, si compruebas el estado del `Dataset` (propiedad `State`) después de hacer el `ApplyUpdates`, encontrarás que está a `dsBrowse`.

De ahí que al intentar hacer el `Post` obtengas ese error.

Comment: En este caso yo estoy queriendo aplicar el update sobre la propia TFDQuery, segun estuve leyendo deberia de poderse hacer la modificacion igual en la bases de datos